# Click event on component root not working

Tags: event-handling, svelte

I'm new to Svelte and I'm trying to put an on:click event on a custom component root (in Vue I use to solve this by writing v-on:click.native=...), but it seems I'm doing something wrong because the event is not firing.
I wrote a simple example on Svelte repl [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/61c34959145747f0a6a555120d653a29?version=3.18.2). The click event fires on the 'div' element, but not on the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Svelte doesn't automatically proxy native events from the root element of a component, because Svelte components are not required to have a single root element (or any elements at all).

So you have to wire the event yourself in the component.

You could go all the way with [`createEventDispatcher`](https://svelte.dev/docs#createEventDispatcher), but there's also a shortcut syntax for precisely what you want to do, proxying native DOM events.

> If the on: directive is used without a value, the component will forward the event, meaning that a consumer of the component can listen for it.

[docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_element_event)

So, with your example, something like this:

```html
<div on:click>
    <h2>
        {book.title}
    </h2>
    <h5>
        {book.author}
    </h5>
</div>
```