# why button on:click does not work in svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte

I want to show a text input field whenever changeEmail is true. So I handleClick to set it to true. However, when I click on a button nothing happens. Would appreciate any help.

```
  let changeEmail = false;

 function handleClick() {
   console.log(changeEmail)
    changeEmail = !changeEmail;
  }
  $: changeEmail;
</script>

<div class="card">

  <div class="info-column">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <div class="info-field">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      {userModel.firstName} {userModel.lastName}
    </div>
    <div class="info-field">
      <h4>Email</h4>
      {#if changeEmail === false}
        {userModel.email}
      {:else}
        <TextInput placeholder="${userModel.email}"/>
      {/if}
      <Button on:click={handleClick}>Edit</Button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is a component that looks like this on page

```
<section>

  <PersonalSettingsCard userModel={$user}>

  </PersonalSettingsCard>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click event on component root not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347074/click-event-on-component-root-not-working)

Comment: I just changed the Button component line with html button element, it works fine,

`<button on:click={handleClick}>Edit</button>`

Answer (score 2):

Like H.B. said and wrote, the click event needs to be forwarded to the Button component. Here is an example in context [from the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dom-event-forwarding) (which I highly recommend completing if you haven't).

I also created a minimal [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e6c9378998ac4a6fa2e54e1d2620055d?version=3.52.0) where the click event works with a custom `<Button>`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no errors (e.g. from `userModel` being `null`/`undefined`), the problem should be your `Button` component, using a native `button` element this will work just fine.

The component has to forward the event for it be usable outside.

```html
<!-- In the Button component -->
<button on:click> ... </button>
```

[Docs for `on:event`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname) (see section after modifiers)

If the `Button` component comes from some library, you have to check what events are provided (though most would just forward `click` as one would expect).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that does not work either. I changed to <button...> and even tried to console.log something on:click with no result

Comment: Then create a minimal reproducible example first (you should do that anyway before asking a question). You might be able to identify the issue that way, and if not, people will be able find the real problem if you provide all the code. Toggling a local boolean and using it in an `#if` is the most basic thing possible, so if it does not work, all your other code is to blame. Also check the console for errors.

Comment: Any errors in console from other libraries etc will stop these events from working.  I couldn't get the "minimally working example" from this thread to actually work until I fixed an unrelated error in console from a different component.